# jQTouch Tabbar slides away when clicked

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I am using jQTouch beta 4 (latest from http://www.jqtouch.com/) with jqt.bars extension from DataZombies (https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch). It seems to be working well, apart from when I click on one of the items in the tab bar, the tab bar itself slides away (to the left). The only way to get it back is to refresh the page. It does also navigate to the correct page, BTW.

Has anyone had the same problem, or does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh... figured it out by trawling the code. I needed to add `class="keep_tabbar"` to each of my page `<div/>` elements.